# Is space considered a word boundary when using [[:<:]][[:>:]]?

Tags: mysql, regex, cpu-word, word-boundaries

I'm trying to create a pretty simple search query which matches whatever the search term but on full words so partial matches are out of the question e.g.

The string to look for is:

```
" (This is) my test string "
```

and the matching queries could be:

```
"This is"
"(This is)"
"(This is"
"This is)"
"my test"
"string"
```

etc. but not:

```
"This is my"
"(thi"
"my tes"
```

etc. as these are only partial matches. LIKE is of no use here so I'm trying with REGEXP and word boundaries:

```
1. SELECT " (This is) my test string " REGEXP "(^|[[:<:]])this is([[:>:]]|$)"; -> 1
2. SELECT " (This is) my test string " REGEXP "(^|[[:<:]])\\(this is\\)([[:>:]]|$)"; -> 0
3. SELECT " This is my test string " REGEXP "(^|[[:<:]])this is([[:>:]]|$)"; -> 1
```

The question is now why don't boundaries in pt.2 cover spaces whereas they seem to in pt.3 (round brackets removed thos show the difference)? What am I missing here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented under [Regular Expressions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/regexp.html):

> These markers stand for word boundaries. They match the beginning and end of words, respectively. A word is a sequence of word characters that is not preceded by or followed by word characters. A word character is an alphanumeric character in the `alnum` class or an underscore (`_`).

Since `)` is *not* a word character, the pattern `\)[[:>:]]` can *never* be matched; `[[:>:]]\)`, on the other hand, *would* be matched.